# don't understand scalaz endo function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, implicit-conversion, scalaz

In scalaz, the `endo` function in `Function1Ops` is implemented this way:

```
def endo(implicit ev: R =:= T): Endo[T] =
  Endo.endo(t => ev(self(t)))
```

I am curious why in the body of `Endo.endo` function, not just simply taking the self... as `Endo.endo(self)`, which behaves the same as `Endo.endo(t=> ev(self(t)))`.

Here is my mimic implementation and I see no difference between the two. Did I miss something?

```
def endo[R, T](f: R => T)(implicit ev: T =:= R) = (x: R)=> ev(f(x))
def endo2[R, T](f: R => T)(implicit ev: T =:= R) = f
```

Besides, doesn't the first implementation add some overhead at runtime?

Comment: I believe, the best place to ask this kind of questions is the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/scalaz. #scalaz@irc.freenode.net is a right place to raise this kind of questions too. You can also just send a pull request to the github repo: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz.

Answer (score 4):

The `Endo.endo` function requires a `A => A`. The `self` value is a function `T => R` which does not comply with the `Endo` requirement.

You could in theory cast `T => R` to `T => T` but the `ev` parameter is created so you don't need to cast and accidentally make the mistake that `T => R` is not equal to `T => T`.

They however could have written it like this:

```
def endo(implicit ev: R =:= T): Endo[T] =
  Endo.endo(self andThen ev)
```

Your examples compile because the returntype is not set.

Comment: thanks a lot. I missed taking into consideration of the return type.